# Microsoft teams, how to recive messages to node.js server?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to get messageContent from microsoft Graph-Api. I am using subscribtion notification that return me a data resources when message occure in  specyfic team in ms teams. With helps this data i can use
`GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages/{message-id}`. If i undestand corretly i need protected Api to make it

Is it possible to do get access to protected api without azure paid subscription? Maybe exist other method to get message content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for Azure paid subscription to access the protected api.
These APIs require that you have additional validation beyond permissions and consent before you can use them.

To request access to these protected APIs, complete the following [request form](https://forms.office.com/pages/responsepage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR1ax4zKyZjVBmutzKVo1pVtURTVXM0wzSldCTjVERDlYRE1WWktQRDhURCQlQCN0PWcu).

Reference Document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis#request-access-to-protected-apis